# How get file path from property file and pass into the method as arguments

Tags: java

In Property file:

**FolderPath**=C:\pre-configured/Import.csv

In Main class im passing this path as argument for a method load

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
new CSV().load(con,"pro.FolderPath", "VALIDATION");
```

but it is giving error as:

```
pro.getProperty(FolderPath) (The system cannot find the file specified.)
```

Please help in passing this path into the method as argument.

Comment: Show us your load method

Comment: public void load(Connection connection,String csvFile, String tableName)

Comment: What about method body?

Comment: Actually post full code as its not very clear.

Comment: My Question is, How to pass the FolderPath Defined in Property file into this Method new CSV().load(con,"pro.FolderPath", "VALIDATION"); When i pass path manually it works. But i want to load path from property file. How to do that?

Comment: I get it now. you are missing the part of loading the property file . See answer from Tim Herold.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load a Properties file first:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( "your properties file path" );

Properties prop2 = new Properties();
prop2.load( reader );
prop2.list( System.out );
```